# How do I write an Expl3 equivalent?

Tags: expl3

I have a command that I can *easily* write using a mixture of resources from `xparse`, `etoolbox`, and `pgffor`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeatletter

\def\ae@tmp@frontmatter{}
\def\ae@list{}
\NewDocumentCommand\qchoice{ mom }
  {%%
    \def\ae@tmp@frontmatter{#2}
    \let\ae@list\relax
    \foreach \myn in {#3}
    {%%
      \ifx\ae@list\relax
        \xdef\ae@list{\noexpand#1{\expandonce\ae@tmp@frontmatter\expandonce\myn}}%%
      \else
        \xdef\ae@list{\expandonce\ae@list
                      \noexpand\par
                      \noexpand#1{\expandonce\ae@tmp@frontmatter\expandonce\myn}}%%
      \fi
    }%%
    \ae@list}

\makeatother

\newcommand\aebf[1]{$\rightarrow$ \textbf{#1} DONE}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\qchoice\aebf[front matter::]{a,b,c,d}

\end{document}
```

However, I would like to be able to write the equivalent of the above using `Expl3` syntax.  (Among other things, the mixing of `\makeatletter` in conjunction with `xparse` just seems *philosophically* wrong.)

It seems I should be able to do this without having to use either `pgffor` or `etoolbox`.  But I keep running into problems.

Here's my latest attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N  \l_qchoice_command_sequence_tl
\tl_new:N  \l_qchoice_front_matter_tl
\tl_new:N  \l_qchoice_csv_choices_tl
\tl_new:N  \l_qchoice_tmp_tl
\seq_new:N \l_qchoice_choices_seq 

\NewDocumentCommand\qchoice{ mom }
  {%%
    \tl_set:Nn  \l_qchoice_command_sequence_tl {#1}
    \tl_clear:N \l_qchoice_front_matter_tl
    \tl_clear:N \l_qchoice_csv_choices_tl
    \IfNoValueF{#2}
      {
        \tl_set:Nn \l_qchoice_front_matter_tl {#2}
      }
    \seq_set_split:Nnn   \l_qchoice_choices_seq {,} {#3}
    \seq_map_function:NN \l_qchoice_choices_seq \qchoice_parse_choices:n
    \l_qchoice_csv_choices_tl
  }

\cs_new:Npn \qchoice_parse_choices:n #1 
  {
    \tl_clear:N      \l_qchoice_tmp_tl
    \tl_set:No       \l_qchoice_tmp_tl \l_qchoice_front_matter_tl
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_qchoice_tmp_tl {#1}
    \tl_set:No       \l_qchoice_tmp_tl {{\l_qchoice_tmp_tl}}
    \tl_put_left:Nn  \l_qchoice_tmp_tl  \l_qchoice_command_sequence_tl
    \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_qchoice_csv_choices_tl
      {
        \tl_set:No        \l_qchoice_csv_choices_tl \l_qchoice_tmp_tl
      }
      {
        \tl_put_right:Nn  \l_qchoice_csv_choices_tl {\par}
        \tl_put_right:No  \l_qchoice_csv_choices_tl {\l_qchoice_tmp_tl}
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\aebf[1]{$\rightarrow$ \textbf{#1} DONE}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\qchoice\aebf[front matter::]{a,b,c,d}

\end{document}
```

There seems to be a problem with the line

```
    \tl_set:No       \l_qchoice_tmp_tl {{\l_qchoice_tmp_tl}}
```

resulting in exceeding TeX capacity error.  But the syntax seems fine to me since `\l_qchoice_tmp_tl` should be expanded once leaving its content to be assigned back to `\l_qchoice_tmp_tl`.  But that's not what seems to be happening.

The `Expl3` code seems to be getting very complicated, which is fine if that's merely because I'm restricting myself to only using `LaTeX3` resources.

**Update**

Ultimately what I want to do is when given

```
\qchoices<control sequence>[<optional front matter>]{<item a>,<item b>,<item c>,<item d>}
```

is produce a string of tokens like

```
<control sequence>{<optional front matter><item a>}<inter-item matter>
<control sequence>{<optional front matter><item b>}<inter-item matter>
<control sequence>{<optional front matter><item c>}<inter-item matter>
<control sequence>{<optional front matter><item d>}
```

where in the above examples I'm using `\par` as my `<inter-item matter>`.  Notice that `<inter-item matter>` should not follow the last item passed.

What I'm having difficulty doing with the `Expl3` code is getting the contents to be passed to `<control sequence>` wrapped in brackets.

Comment: Do you need the result stored in a list: if not the outcome is trivially easy.

Comment: @JosephWright  In my original document, I have a function that expects to receive a string of tokens separated by commas.  So, I kind of need `\l_qchoice_csv_choices_tl` to be such a `csv` list.  But, I'm also open to seeing how someone else might approach this too.

Comment: After playing around with this a bit more, the problem seems to be around the doubly nested brackets in the line where I'm trying to expand the token once and reassign to itself.

Comment: I don't follow: in your 'reference' version `\ae@list` ends up as `\aebf {front matter::a}\par \aebf {front matter::b}\par \aebf {front matter::c}\par \aebf {front matter::d}`: no commas here. Do you need a command which produces this list of tokens or one that simply typesets it?

Comment: @JosephWright Sorry, you're right.  That's a result of my minimizing my example.  So, let's say that it's really that my function expects a `\par` token separate list.

Comment: @JosephWright I need a command which produces the list of tokens, not one that typesets it (that's left of later macros to handle).

Comment: I wouldn't write `\tl_set:No \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpb_tl`, I would put braces around the second argument (`o` is not *one token*). By the way, why `\tl_set:No` and not `\tl_set_eq:NN` or `\tl_set:NV`? (I didn't read the whole question yet, jsut suggesting) **ADD:** “But the syntax seems fine to me since `\l_qchoice_tmp_tl` should be expanded once leaving its content to be assigned back to `\l_qchoice_tmp_tl`” It's not expanded, only the first `{`.

Comment: @Manuel I'm not sure what you're saying.  Does `o` expect just one token?  If so, that's not clear from the manual.  Also, I've updated the question to clarify a bit more what I'm trying to create.

Comment: @Manuel Isn't that how `\tl_set:Nf` would behave?  Shouldn't `\tl_set:No` expand the second argument once, not just half way?

Comment: @A.Ellett Just the opposite. It's not one token, so it should have `{ .. }` around the second argument. Expanding once `{\tmp}` (braces included in the expansion) is done by `\expandafter{{\tmp}}` so `\expandafter` only affects the first two tokens (saves one and expands the second) hence `\expandafter{{` does nothing. (I'm not a pro, just my thoughts :P)

Comment: @A.Ellett I've added another paragraph to the docs about `o`-type expansion. We promote `V`-type where possible as it's conceptually easier to explain: `o`-type is low-level and relies on TeX as a macro expansion language much more.

Comment: @Manuel I'd welcome some thoughts on where best to explain this and a good piece of text that is clear to the 'non-pro' (you are quite right about what happens).

Comment: @JosephWright I think it's clear enough. Expanding once means expand the leftmost token once (since expansion goes from left to right), it doesn't mean expanding all macros once (i.e., `\empty\@empty` doesn't expand to nothing with `o` but to `\@empty`). But I think there's nothing much to say apart from that the system is `\expandafter{..}`. **EDIT:** I think the `\expandafter` is just mentioned in expl3.pdf and not in interface3.pdf.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While you could construct the result here one part at a time I would arrange to do the entire job inside an `x`-type expansion using a mapping. As the input is a comma list it's probably easiest to do this directly

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_qchoice_choices_tl
\cs_new:Npn \__qhoice_tmp:n #1 { }
\NewDocumentCommand \qchoice { m o m }
  {
    \tl_clear:N \l_qchoice_csv_tl
    \cs_set:Npn \__qhoice_tmp:n ##1
      {
        \exp_not:N #1
          {
            \IfNoValueF {#2} { \exp_not:n {#2} }
            \exp_not:n {##1}
          }
        \exp_not:N \par
      }
    \tl_set:Nx \l_qchoice_csv_tl
      {
        \clist_map_function:nN {#3}\__qhoice_tmp:n
      }
    \tl_show:N \l_qchoice_csv_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\aebf[1]{$\rightarrow$ \textbf{#1} DONE}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\qchoice\aebf[front matter::]{a,b,c,d}

\end{document}
```

For the case where you don't want the separator to appear after the last item there are a few approaches. Perhaps the conceptually easiest is to use an inline mapping where there is a test to see if the list is empty: in that case don't add the separator.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_qchoice_choices_tl
\cs_new:Npn \__qhoice_tmp:n #1 { }
\NewDocumentCommand \qchoice { m o m }
  {
    \tl_clear:N \l_qchoice_csv_tl
    \clist_map_inline:nn {#3}
      {
        \tl_set:Nx \l_qchoice_csv_tl
          {
            \exp_not:V \l_qchoice_csv_tl
            \tl_if_empty:NF \l_qchoice_csv_tl
              { \exp_not:N \par }
            \exp_not:N #1
              {
                \IfNoValueF {#2} { \exp_not:n {#2} }
                \exp_not:n {##1}
              }
          }
      }
    \tl_show:N \l_qchoice_csv_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\aebf[1]{$\rightarrow$ \textbf{#1} DONE}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\qchoice\aebf[front matter::]{a,b,c,d}

\end{document}
```

This approach needs one assignment per item: if more efficiency is needed, there are alternatives (the question suggests the list is short).

As noted in comments, `\tl_set:No \l_tmpa_tl { { \l_tmpa_tl } }` tries to expand `{` not `\l_tmpa_tl` (`\tl_set:No` is low-ish level and equivalent to `\exp_after:wN \tl_set:Nn \exp_after:wN`). Usually it's best to avoid building up complex token lists a bit at a time if you can arrange to do the job in one go using an `x`-type expansion: only one assignment is needed and this is a performance gain.

Comment: Nice job, but this will place `\par` after the last item `d` which I don't want to have happen.

Comment: @A.Ellett That was not clear from the question: I'll revise.

Comment: I've updated the question to better reflect that idea too.  :)

Comment: Note that in both approaches I've avoided adding too many things stepwise: that gets slow (ongoing work on `siunitx` involves exactly this point).

Comment: I hadn't wanted to build things step by step as I did in the `Expl3` code.  Thank you for the solution:  seeing the use of `\exp_not:*` greatly helped as did the discussion with @manuel about how `:o` works.